# How to define model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, model

I defined a classification model in tensorflow in two ways that I thought have the same effect. But actually I got different results.
The first way is defining model through functions:

```
def network(x, mode_name):
    conv1 = conv_layer(x, conv_size=[13, 13, 1, 32], stride_size=[1, 1, 1, 1], name=mode_name + "conv1")
    maxp1 = pooling_layer(conv1, ksize=[1, 4, 4, 1], stride_size=[1, 4, 4, 1])
    conv2 = conv_layer(maxp1, conv_size=[7, 7, 32, 64], stride_size=[1, 1, 1, 1], name=mode_name + "conv2")
    maxp2 = pooling_layer(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], stride_size=[1, 2, 2, 1])
    conv3 = conv_layer(maxp2, conv_size=[3, 3, 64, 256], stride_size=[1, 1, 1, 1], name=mode_name + "conv3")
    maxp3 = pooling_layer(conv3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], stride_size=[1, 2, 2, 1])
    shape = maxp3.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(maxp3, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    fc = fc_layer(reshape, label_number, name=mode_name + "fc")
    return fc

def fc_layer(prev_layer, n_weight, name):
    n_prev_weight = prev_layer.get_shape()[1]
    initer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.0001)
    W = tf.get_variable(name + 'W', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[n_prev_weight, n_weight], initializer=initer)
    b = tf.get_variable(name + "b", dtype=tf.float32,
                    initializer=tf.constant(0.0001, shape=[n_weight], dtype=tf.float32))
    fc = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(prev_layer, W), b)
    return fc


def conv_layer(prev_layer, conv_size, stride_size, name):
    initer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.0001)
    W = tf.get_variable(name + 'W', dtype=tf.float32, shape=conv_size,
                    initializer=initer)
    b = tf.get_variable(name + 'b', dtype=tf.float32,
                    initializer=tf.constant(0.0001, shape=[conv_size[3]], dtype=tf.float32))

    return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(prev_layer, W, stride_size, padding='VALID') + b)

def pooling_layer(prev_layer, ksize, stride_size):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(prev_layer, ksize=ksize, strides=stride_size, padding='VALID')
```

and then use these function in `main`:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    # input data
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                      shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, image_channel))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                     shape=(batch_size, label_number))
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    with tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn") as scope:
        logits = network(tf_train_dataset, "simple_cnn")

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf_train_labels))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)

    with tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn") as scope:
        scope.reuse_variables()
        test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(network(tf_test_dataset, "simple_cnn"))
```

The other way is to allocate all the variables and define the model in `main`:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    # input data
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                      shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, image_channel))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                     shape=(batch_size, label_number))
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    initer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)
    conv_w1 = tf.get_variable(name="conv_w1", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[13, 13, 1, 32], initializer=initer)
    conv_b1 = tf.get_variable(name="conv_b1", dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[32, ], dtype=tf.float32))
    conv_w2 = tf.get_variable(name="conv_w2", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[7, 7, 32, 64], initializer=initer)
    conv_b2 = tf.get_variable(name="conv_b2", dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[64, ], dtype=tf.float32))
    conv_w3 = tf.get_variable(name="conv_w3", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3, 3, 64, 256], initializer=initer)
    conv_b3 = tf.get_variable(name="conv_b3", dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[256, ], dtype=tf.float32))
    fc_w = tf.get_variable(name='fc_w', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2304, label_number], initializer=initer)
    fc_b = tf.get_variable(name="fc_b", dtype=tf.float32,
                           initializer=tf.constant(0.0001, shape=[label_number, ], dtype=tf.float32))


    def model(x):
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_w1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + conv_b1
        relu1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
        maxp1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, ksize=[1, 4, 4, 1], strides=[1, 4, 4, 1], padding='VALID')

        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(maxp1, conv_w2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID") + conv_b2
        relu2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
        maxp2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')

        conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(maxp2, conv_w3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
        relu3 = tf.nn.relu(conv3)
        maxp3 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')

        shape = maxp3.get_shape().as_list()

        reshape = tf.reshape(maxp3, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
        fc = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(reshape, fc_w), fc_b)
        return fc

    logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf_train_labels))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)

    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))
```

I think the two ways are actually defining the same model. But when I trained them, it happened that the first way has no effect in decreasing the cost [image: failure-result] and model defined in the second way is successful[image: success]. Don't care the model itself, I just wonder what caused such a difference? The input data are both the same.

Comment: Looks like you didn't update the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your variables.

```
with tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn") as scope:
    scope.reuse_variables()
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(network(tf_test_dataset, "simple_cnn"))
```

In the first model, the test variables names should have an extra `simple_cnn/`. So you are using for your test not learned variables.

Look at [Sharing Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables) example to understand how to share variables. In your case, put everything under the same scope (i.e. the `with tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn") ...` should be put before the training model too).

Comment: Just as you said, I change the code as follow:

        with tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn") as scope:
            logits = network(tf_train_dataset)
            scope.reuse_variables()
            test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(network(tf_test_dataset))

        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, 
labels=tf_train_labels))
and it works. But I still don't know why. I read the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) and think the test variables are just same as the training ones.

Comment: The official example:
 with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
assert v1 is v
is just like what I used in the first model. Maybe it's just because I put the scope before the training model?

Comment: When you use the `tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn")` you are adding a `simple_cnn` to all the names of the variables. This were the only difference between your two pieces of code. When tensorflow reuse variables, it uses their names. Adding the same scope in the test, make you use the same trained variables, while before you are just using random values.

Comment: For clarifying, in the first model, training variables are named `simple_cnn/(other_things)` while your testing variables are named `simple_cnn/simple_cnn/(other_things)`.